# How to generate Excel Chart with this grouping

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

Assume the following data on a sheet:

```
date        source      type hits
2019/08/01  Source A    1    3
2019/08/01  Source B    1    2
2019/08/01  Source A    2    19
2019/08/01  Source D    2    10
2019/08/01  Source E    2    31
2019/08/01  Source F    2    1
2019/08/01  Source B    2    1
2019/08/01  Source G    2    3
2019/08/01  Source C    5    1
2019/08/01  Source A    5    1
2019/08/01  Source E    5    1
2019/08/01  Source H    5    1
2019/07/01  Source A    1    4
2019/07/01  Source B    1    10
2019/07/01  Source A    2    56
2019/07/01  Source I    2    24
2019/07/01  Source D    2    3
2019/07/01  Source E    2    23
2019/07/01  Source B    2    3
2019/07/01  Source C    5    8
2019/07/01  Source A    5    1
2019/06/01  Source A    1    17
2019/06/01  Source B    1    2
2019/06/01  Source A    2    23
2019/06/01  Source I    2    33
2019/06/01  Source D    2    2
2019/06/01  Source E    2    36
2019/06/01  Source A    4    2
2019/06/01  Source C    5    3
2019/05/01  Source A    1    10
2019/05/01  Source A    2    22
2019/05/01  Source I    2    62
2019/05/01  Source D    2    9
2019/05/01  Source E    2    17
2019/05/01  Source C    5    10
2019/04/01  Source A    1    20
2019/04/01  Source A    2   30
2019/04/01  Source I    2   59
2019/04/01  Source D    2   12
2019/04/01  Source E    2   69
2019/04/01  Source J    2   5
2019/04/01  Source C    5   8
2019/04/01  Source I    5   1
2019/04/01  Source E    5   1
2019/03/01  Source A    1   28
2019/03/01  Source A    2   32
2019/03/01  Source I    2   86
2019/03/01  Source D    2   11
2019/03/01  Source E    2   68
2019/03/01  Source K    2   1
2019/03/01  Source C    5   4
2019/03/01  Source L    5   1
2019/03/01  Source A    5   1
2019/03/01  Source I    5   1
2019/03/01  Source E    5   3
```

I want to make a line chart, where the X axis is the data grouped by the month (or date, since they will always be the first of a month).
The Y axis is the hits. The various lines/colours are the source.

Now for the tricky bit, There should be either 1 chart where I can select the type from a drop down, or simply 5 separate charts showing the data filtered to its type. How does one accomplish this?

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1474108/edit) to provide a sample of what the final chart should look like (a smaller data set matching the chart would also be good)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quickest and easiest (but not most robust) option is to use a Pivot Table and Pivot Chart.

1. Convert your data into an Excel Table `Insert>Table`
   [image]
2. Create a Pivot Table from your Table `Insert>Pivot Table`
3. Setup your Pivot Table:

   - Values = Sum of hits
   - Rows = date
   - Columns = source
   - Filter = type

[image]

4. Create a Pivot Chart `Insert>Chart>2-D Line` while a cell in your Pivot Table is selected.

[image]

5. Format to taste (although options are limited by the Pivot Chart)
6. Use the Pivot Chart or Pivot Table Filter to select a type to focus on.

Comment: perfect - thank you